# How can I count the alphabat of column 2 against similar number of column one in R?

Tags: loops, count

```
C1  C2
1   a      
1   a
1   x  
1   z 
2   a
2   y 
3   x
3   x
3   x
3   z
```

I have the data in two columns **C1** and **C2**. I want the output in the form how many time alphabet occure against a specific number of C1.

For example select all the number "1" from column one and then search how many time alphabet occure against the selected number. and then go for the next number of column one, do the same thing and so on till last.
The output should be as following:

```
1   a(2)      
    x(1)
    z(1)  
2   a(1)      
    y(1) 
3   x(3)      
    z(1)
```

Please suggest me how can I get the desired output.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please describe the language you plan to use, as well as tagging the question as such

Comment: I am interested to do this in R.

Comment: Please tag/edit the question, not just say this in comments